# Browser not displaying images when embedded

Tags: html, image

If you go to http://cartpauj.icomnow.com/ you'll see that the images in the HTML are not showing up. Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/MrL6

The src to the images is 100% correct and if I browse directly to the image file in my browser it shows up. Screenshot with Element Inspector in Chrome: http://cl.ly/Mrlt

Yet when I browse to that image directly it shows up fine. I would post a link to the image but I cannot because I don't have 10 reputation points here. You can see the URL to the image in the screenshot above.

I've checked .htaccess for any strange rules but nothing wrong in it. Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this to be happening?

Comment: FYI, problem ended being hotlink rules in the .htaccess file in the directory above where my site was stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that requests for your images like this one:

http://cartpauj.icomnow.com/wp-content/uploads/logoBig.png

Are redirecting to http://icomnow.com.  This is only happening when the `Referer` header is set (which happens when you load the image from a page, vs. directly).  You probably have a broken re-write rule causing this.

Other broken images:

- /wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Blue_store1.jpg
- /wp-content/themes/simplex/images/logo-simpleX.png
- /wp-content/uploads/2011/05/istore-banner125.png
- /wp-content/uploads/2011/05/android-logo-white-150x1501.png
- /wp-content/uploads/logoBig.png
- /wp-content/uploads/2010/11/plugin_store250x1251.gif
- /wp-content/uploads/ads/icomnowad125.jpg
- /wp-content/themes/simplex/images/arrows-ffffff.png
- /wp-content/uploads/ads/icomnowad125.jpg
- /wp-content/uploads/logoBig.png
- /wp-content/uploads/logoBig.png

You can use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to find these easily.

Comment: check out this [post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-blogs-images-not-showing) which looks like the same problem with re-write rules